# xcode5 iOS Simulator failed to install the application

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

Recently i installed X-Code 5 on my new Mac-mini, and created a iOS project with "Single View Application" template.(I haven't added any code). when i run the application i got the error "**iOS Simulator failed to install the application.**" The deployment target and Base SDK are set to iOS 7.

The simulator screen is blank as [in this stack overflow question][1]

also the following Simulator menu options are not working.

1.Debug->Open System log

2.Hardware->Home,Lock & Toggle in call status bar

Here is the Simulator error log.

```
    iPhone Simulator[804] <Error>: Could not lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge: 3
    iPhone Simulator[804] <Error>: Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
    iPhone Simulator[804] <Error>: Could not lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.host_support: 3
    iPhone Simulator[804] <Error>: Unable to update keyboard layout because we were unable to connect to the host_support mach service.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a known bug in Xcode 5.0.1. The updated version 5.0.2 addresses this issue

Answer (score 2):

Here is the concrete solution to your problem,

1. launch the iOS Simulator
2. Go and click "iOS Simulator" Menu
3. click "Reset content and settings"
4. close simulator and rebuild your app.

[image]

Above screen shot is showing the way how you can do this...

I think this works for you...!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Reset Content and Settings of the simulator
2. Quit Xcode
3. Quit Simulator
4. Try again